# Custom Silverstripe Report Filter isn't being applied till manual page refresh

Tags: filter, report, silverstripe

I'm working on this custom report in SilverStripe and when I filter the report SilverStripe reloads the page but the filter doesn't get applied. But if I hit the refresh button or press f5 and reload the page myself, then the filter is applied successfully. Any help at all would be really appreciated.

This is a simplified and less identifying version of what I have:

```
public function sourceRecords($params){
    $data = Data::get();
    $records = [];
    $filterParam = 0;

    if (isset($params["filterParam"])
        $filterParam = $params["filterParam"];

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item->value == $filterParam) {
            $records[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList($records, "Data");
}

public function columns() {
    return array ("value" => "Value");
}

public function parameterFields() {
    return new FieldList(
        new TextField("FilterParam", _t("MyCustomReport.FilterParam", "Filter Param"), 0);
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out. If anyone else is having a similar issue the problem stems from using a standard array, and creating an ArrayList using that array. When I switch to just using an ArrayList right from the beginning the filter works properly.

The corrected code:

```
public function sourceRecords($params){
    $data = Data::get();
    $records = new ArrayList(); // This is now new ArrayList instead of []
    $filterParam = 0;

    if (isset($params["filterParam"])
        $filterParam = $params["filterParam"];

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item->value == $filterParam) {
            $records->push($item); // changed to use the correct syntax for ArrayList
        }
    }
    return $records; // No longer making new ArrayList here
}
```

No changes to the other functions were needed.